# How to cancel delivery of sticky message once delivered (GreenRobot-EventBus)

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am posting a sticky event from an Activity, lets call this activity A. I successfully receive this event  in Activity B. I go to Activity C and again come back to activity B as I come back the receive the same event which I received earlier. I understand that as I have posted a sticky event I have received it again, but how to work around this problem? I tried `EventBus.getDefault().cancelEventDelivery(message);` but it gives an error `de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: This method may only be called from inside event handling methods on the posting thread`
I put a log to check the `Thread` which was posting and receiving the event. Both show it as the `main` thread.
Can anyone suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove sticky event: 
   Fallow documentation:
   https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md

   > It's also possible to remove previously posted sticky events using one
   >   of the removeStickyEvent methods. They take either a concrete event
   >   object, or an event class. Like this it's possible to create
   >   consumable events. Keep in mind though that that only the last event
   >   of an event type is kept.
2. idea is create your event consumable. Ex:

   ```
   public class SomeStivyEvent { 
       public void boolean consumed = false;  

       public void consumed(){
            consumed = true;
       } 
   }
   ```